# Gitlab Renew lets encrypt certificate failed

Tags: lets-encrypt, gitlab-ce

I am trying to renew GitLab letsencrypt certificate for my standalone Gitlab-ce installation.

But it failed for some reason.

the result is as follow,

```
Acme::Client::Error::Timeout
----------------------------
Acme::Client::Error::Timeout

chef_version=15.17.4
platform=ubuntu
platform_version=20.04
ruby=ruby 2.7.5p203 (2021-11-24 revision f69aeb8314) [x86_64-linux]
program_name=/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chef-client
executable=/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chef-client


Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Infra Client failed. 0 resources updated in 01 minutes 05 seconds
There was an error renewing Let's Encrypt certificates, please checkout the output
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Is your instance publically accessible on ports 80/443? Did letsencrypt ever work for you before? Can you please provide your relevant configurations?

Comment: @sytech yes, it works till the date of expiry without any issues. automatic renewal failed so i jus try to renew with `gitlab-ctl renew-le-certs` command and it will ran into the above error.

Comment: @systech also I have doubt with `chef_version=15.17.4` .  Is any update is available?

Answer (score 5):

I solved the same problem by clearing all the certificates (.crt and .key files) in /etc/gitlab/ssl and then running `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`. it made new ones.
This might not be a good solution for everyone but in my case, it worked. Also, I found that the /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb had several 'nil' values in the letsencrypt area including whether it was enabled and the minute value that the generator is supposed to run at. I set the minute value to 0, as well as `letsencrypt['enable'] = true`

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Lets Encrypt certificates should [automatically renew on the 4th day of the month](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/ssl/#renew-the-certificates-automatically) (with a minutes offset that is determined by the hash of the `external_url`).

To [manually renew](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/ssl/#renew-the-certificates-manually), you are using the correct method: `sudo gitlab-ctl renew-le-certs`. [Reza's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73009528/776953) is *also* a correct method for manual renew. The manual renewals will only actually renew, if your current LE TLS is "close to expiry".

Also, consider the upstream [rate limits at Let's Encrypt themselves](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/). The error message mentions to check the output to see why it actually failed, and that appears to be a timeout from LE for the Acme client, so it's *probably* what happened in this case. Let's Encrypt offer some good advice on that page, such as to [use their staging environment](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/ssl/#use-an-acme-server-other-than-lets-encrypt) if you are actively testing, rather than hitting their production servers.